# Cocos2d v3 Human Physics

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

I am trying to make a new game in Cocos2d v3. The basic gameplay that I want is to have a humanoid player bend down and then jump off of things. I want to make it that the player become a ragdoll if they don't land the jump. Right now I create the player (which is the body of the character) and add all the other pieces to that class. I do it like this:

```
    //Thigh
    _thigh = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"thigh.png"];
    _thigh.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f, 1);

    _thigh.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _thigh.contentSize.width, _thigh.contentSize.height) cornerRadius:0];
    _thigh.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"playerGroup"; // 2
    _thigh.physicsBody.collisionType  = @"playerCollision";

    _thigh.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    _thigh.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width * 0.5f, -_thigh.contentSize.height * (1.0f - _thigh.anchorPoint.y));

    _thigh.physicsBody.mass = 2;

    [self addChild:_thigh];

    CCPhysicsJoint* hipJoint = [CCPhysicsJoint connectedDistanceJointWithBodyA:self.physicsBody
                                                                         bodyB:_thigh.physicsBody
                                                                       anchorA:ccp(self.contentSize.width * 0.5f, 0)
                                                                       anchorB:ccp(_thigh.contentSize.width * 0.5f, _thigh.contentSize.height)];
```

When the character is in the air I want to have the character is certain positions. Since the pieces are connected with joints, when I use the rotate action it makes the whole character jitter. If I use angular velocity, the pieces seem to pull the other ones around and don't end up in the correct position.

Is there a way that I can create a humanoid character, that can be a ragdoll, but I can still smoothly control certain body parts?